# Can input in html read spaces?

Tags: c#, input

Can input tags in html read spaces? I am getting a value in my database which is a space and the input tag cannot read it. I am coding in C# not php.

Comment: yes you can.. -- aka bob

Comment: how sir? the input tag does not show the space i am retrieving from the database..

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your problem, you are trying to enter data into a database, and the data is entered via a HTML based input tag, such as text area etc.

The short answer to this is yes - they do and can read spaces, you retrieve the data exactly as is with the possible exception of encoding. If I were to write "Hello, World", you would retrieve "Hello, World". I believe your problem comes from elsewhere in your codebase.

The correct input tag layout:

```
<form>
  Text Here:
  <input type="text" name="text-example" id="example">
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: writing a space in the database works fine but I am retrieving a space only from the database. The textarea can read the space in the database while the space i am retrieving that will go into the <input ../> cannot read the space.

Comment: solved my problem was reading a space at the end of an array which resulted that it cannot read the space